# how to automate Ctrl+n using keys chord function

Tags: selenium-webdriver, key

I am trying to launch a new browser and I tried the below command:

```
element.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "n"));
```

But I get the following error:

> chord is not a function

Can someone let me know if we need to import packages for keys.chord function?
If so, where can I find those?